# OpenSSL with CMake - unknown option: --sysroot when building openSSL

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

i am cross-compiling openSSL 1.1.1 for Android platform, using CMake scripts, since it is a dependency for other libraries i have to use in building my application. So, i had to launch an External sub-build through ExternalProject module commands, running the OpenSSL own build system with proper commands. The final commands looks like something like the following:

```
ExternalProject_Add(openssl
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl
        BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        #INSTALL_DIR
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Starting custom configure"
        COMMAND             export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=@CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK@
        COMMAND             CC=clang;AR=@CMAKE_AR@;RANLIB=@CMAKE_RANLIB@;PATH=${OPENSSL_COMPILER_PATH}:${PERL_PATH}
        COMMAND             ANDROID_NDK_HOME=@CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK@;CC=clang;AR=@CMAKE_AR@;RANLIB=@CMAKE_RANLIB@;PATH=${OPENSSL_COMPILER_PATH}:${PERL_PATH};<SOURCE_DIR>/Configure ${ARCH} no-shared ${CONFIGURE_COMMAND_DEFINITIONS} -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl/ -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl/include -I@CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK@/sysroot/usr/include -I@CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK@/sysroot/usr/include/${ARCH_INCLUDE_DIR} --prefix=@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/@CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR@ --openssldir=$@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/@CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR@ --libdir=""
        BUILD_COMMAND       export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=@CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK@
        COMMAND             PATH=${OPENSSL_COMPILER_PATH}:${PERL_PATH}:/bin
        COMMAND             ANDROID_NDK_HOME=@CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK@;PATH=${OPENSSL_COMPILER_PATH}:${PERL_PATH}:/bin;${MAKE_EXECUTABLE} -j8 build_libs
        INSTALL_COMMAND     ${MAKE_EXECUTABLE} -j8 install_sw
        STEP_TARGETS        build install
        )
```

The build step is ok, but when the install target is built, the following message error appears:

```
ld: unknown option: --sysroot=/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
```

The error is issued after libcrypto and libssl have been created, and script is trying to link them to opensSSL app it is creating. So:
1) Any tip on how solve the issue? I think it's linked to Android SDK using GNU ld instead of Clang lld
2) Is there a way to configure OpenSSL scripts (in particular i am thinking to the templates which produces the Makefile basing on the system we are compiling for) in order to do not install the OpenSSL application and other stuff I am not interested in?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Making target "install_dev" in place of "install" one seems to solve issue 2)...I will further investigate for solution of step 1)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because the linker program 'ld' is given the command line parameter "--sysroot" that it does not support. Your configuration seems to pass this command line parameter to the linker program. If you find out how it does and disable this command line parameter, this could solve the issue.

I do not think that making CMake choose clang lld will solve the issue, because "--sysroot" also is not a command line parameter for lld as far as I could see in the man page here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/llvm-ld